# How To install coherence server in weblogic server

Tags: weblogic-10.x, oracle-coherence

I need to install coherence server in weblogic, I have downloaded weblogic server , but i am unable to setup coherence in weblogic server , pls any body tell me procedure for setup a coherence server in weblogic

Answer (score 1):

There is a version of weblogic that contains built-in coherence. you can find it in following link:

[Weblogic with oracle coherence](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/coherence/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnjp)

Comment: I have installed that weblogic server but i am unable start a coherence server in that weblogic server , can u please tell me procedure to start coherence server

Comment: No need to start it manually. You must add your coherence cluster config to Weblogic and restart weblogic. For adding cluster config, in web console, go to Environments then coherence clusters and click new button.